# Problemas con la librería GD en PHP

Tags: php

Muy buenas!

Tengo un problemita con una pequeña aplicación que estoy haciendo.

La idea es que el usuario suba una imagen a través de un form y yo, "al vuelo", cojo esa imagen y le pongo un faldón que tengo guardado en el server.

El problema es que cargo la foto etc, pero al hacer las acciones con GD no se si es que no carga la imagen o que es pero lo unico que hace es crearme una imagen transparente... https://gyazo.com/7d0b3ce60d3b624e7b074b1c2dbe0511

Adjunto el codigo:

```
<?php



$destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$target_path = $destination_path . basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

var_dump ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$faldondir = $destination_path . 'Faldon_horizontal.png';
@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path);


    $rutaFoto = substr ($target_path ,37);
    $rutaFoto = "XXXXXXX/".$rutaFoto;

    $rutaFaldon = substr ($faldondir ,37);
    $rutaFaldon = "XXXXXXX/".$rutaFaldon;

$im = @imagecreatefromjpeg($rutaFoto );
    if(!$im)
    {

    $anchoimg = imagesx($im);

    $faldon = @imagecreatefrompng($rutaFaldon);
    $anchofaldon = imagesx($faldon);

    var_dump($anchoimg);
    var_dump($anchofaldon);

   if($anchoimg != $anchofaldon)
    {
      $faldon = imagescale ($faldon, $anchoimg);
    }

    $alto = imagesy($im) - imagesy($faldon);

    imagecopyresampled(
      $im,
      $faldon,
      0, $alto, 0, 0,
      imagesx($faldon),
      imagesy($faldon),
      imagesx($faldon),
      imagesy($faldon)
    );
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($im, null, 100);

    } else {
    echo "La imagen no está cargada\n";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

El primer parámetro de la función `imagecopyresampled` es la imagen **destino**, y el segundo parámetro es la imagen **origen**.

En tu código está al reves ;-)

Comment: Exactamente, la imagen de destino donde quiero acoplar el faldón es $im por lo que debe ir en el primera parámetro de la función no?

Comment: Sí correcto, prueba a ver.